# Can I & how do I write a standard file to a directory as the same user no matter which user I write the file as?

Tags: linux

I am working under Linux and I have a directory, `/data/history/export` which has a user `captain` and group `crew`.  I would like users `mike`, `joe`, and `steve` to ALWAYS write to this directory as user `captain`.  I know I can do this using a common group but can I do it so that everything written to this directory becomes `captain`?

Answer (score 2):

Linux ignores directory suid, and I never really understood why. Other systems (fbsd, hpux, solaris) are smart enough to handle subsequent security concerns (eg. binary suid strip).

If John's answer (`chmod g+s /data/history/export`) is not sufficient, you can try `setfacl -RP -m d:u:captain:rwX /data/history/export` to always allow captain access to files and directories created therein as long as the sticky bit (o+s) is unset.

setfacl option explanation:

```
-R apply recursively,
-P physical only, do not exit physical tree via symlink,
-m modify/create,
d: add an inherited default to directories,
u: user specific ACL,
rwX add read and write privs to everything and execute for directories
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot predetermine the user owner of the file, no, but you can force group ownership on all newly created files in a given directory by setting the guid bit on that directory via `chmod g+s <dirname>` or it's functional equivalent.